# Flake8's Mercurial hook raised an exception: 'ui' object has no attribute 'configint'

Tags: python, mercurial, virtualenv, flake8

We are using virtualenv and Mercurial 1.7.5.

To provide better code checking I installed Flake8 and added a mercurial hook to the repository as described here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8

I installed Flake8 in a virtual environment, so I was not surprised with the error I got on commit:  `'ui' object has no attribute 'configint'`. I thought the error would go away upon installing flake8 outside the virtualenv (I thought the 'python:' keyword in the configuration file applies to the system's python interpreter). But the error hasn't gone.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure Flake8 supports the version of Mercurial you're on.  It may be that you're using a newer/older version of Mercurial than Flake8 supports.  Mercurial internals are considered private and subject to change at any time.  Extensions and hooks are expected to use the public Mercurial API: the hg executable.

Comment: The right answer, everything works after Mercurial upgrade. Thank you!